# How to read drl file by using drools API? Is there any function in drools that can parse drl file into some value or other formats?

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am trying to visualize some drl file **not** using drools workbench(or business central). I've found the function to create drl file by passing value. However, I can't find the way to do opposite thing.

I expect to parse the existed drl file into some value or other format that can be easily used in my Vue project. At the moment I am looking for it in Drools souce code but can't find it.

I don't want to use drools workbench because it's not convenient enough to use. But if there are some functions or libraries in its souce code, please let me know. It's also very helpful.

I am using drools 7.0.0.final now.

Thanks for reading my question, if you have any idea, please help me.

Comment: Please specify the version of Drools you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot this. I am using drools 7.0.0.final.

Comment: You want the text from DRL? or you want to get the Rules from Kie Server already loaded in a Drools package (e.g. org.kie.api.definition.rule.Rule)? To make it clear, you want to read / parse DRL file stored in your Kie Server from a java application running remotely? Also what information you want to read from DRL? Conditions and actions? Rule names only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve, but let me give you some hints.

The `org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlParser`  in the `drools-compiler` module will parse the DRL and generate the `PackageDescr`, pretty much an AST of the rule file. Take a look at `org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlParserTest` for an example.

The `org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl` will create the `*Impl*` classes which are used by the runtime of Drools.

Alternatively you can take a look at the `drools-model-compiler` module, in which theres a compiler `org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl` that compiles `*Descrs` into a Java DSL we created recently, the executable model. see `org.drools.modelcompiler.CompilerTest` and `org.drools.modelcompiler.PatternDSLTest`

Let me know if it helps.

Good luck

Comment: So sorry I didn't reply you two years ago...But your advice was very helpful, I transferred drl file into model in Java with the package you mentioned and it works! Thank you!